# What’s the word for an unnecessary statement that must be true given an earlier comment?

Tags: vocabulary

For example, “it was 3am in the morning” or “i saw with my own eyes”.

Comment: "corollary" ---

Comment: [A **tautology** is the opposite of an oxymoron](https://www.alphadictionary.com/goodword/word/tautology) (*It was 3am in the afternoon,* for example, would be a kind of "oxymoron").

Comment: ***Pleonastic***: using.  of more words than are necessary to express an idea; redundancy. https://www.dictionary.com/browse/pleonastic

Comment: I'll suggest you to follow the guidelines directing EL & U. Read- [How do I ask a good question?](https://english.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask) It will help you trailer your question. Remember, healthy question attracts healthy answer(s).

Answer (score 0):

It's ***PLEONASM***:

"the use of more words than those necessary to denote mere sense".

According to [Merriam-Webster's Dictionary](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/pleonasm#note-1) :

Pleonasm, which stems via Late Latin from the Greek verb pleonazein("to be excessive"), is a fancy word for "redundancy."

It's related to our words "plus" and "plenty," and ultimately it goes back to the Greek word for "more," which is "pleōn."

Pleonasm is commonly considered a fault of style, but it can also serve a useful function.

"Extra" words can sometimes be helpful to a speaker or writer in getting a message across, adding emphasis, or simply adding an appealing sound and rhythm to a phrase - as, for example, with the pleonasm 
"***I saw it with my own eyes!"***